# Transform integral bounds for multidimensional integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to transform the followin integral borders into something I can use to integrate the argument of

$$\int_{R^N, \; \|\vec{x}\| \lt \gamma} f(\|\vec{x}\|)  d\vec{x}$$

analytically. The dimensionality is supposed to be $N=4$.

**How can I transform the integral bounds to the form**

$$\int_{s_0}^{e_0} \dots \int_{s_N}^{e_N} f(\dots) \, d x_N \cdots d x_1$$

**where $x_i$ denotes the $i$-th row of $\vec{x}$ and $\|\dots\|$ the $L_2$-norm?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand depends only on the radius $r=\|\vec x\|$. Use multidimensional espherical coordinates:
$$
\int_{R^N, \; \|\vec{x}\| \lt \gamma} f(\|\vec{x}\|)  d\vec{x}=\omega_N\int_0^\gamma f(r)\,r^{N-1}\,dr
$$
where $\omega_N$ is the *area* of $S_{N-1}=\{\vec x\in\mathbb{R}^N:\|\vec x\|=1\}$.

Comment: Can you point me at a book that contains this including a proof?